# How to prevent from adding maven and other unnecessary jars to generated war file? (maven-archetype-webapp archetype)

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3, war

I have created a maven-archetype-webapp using the m2eclipse plugin, and it builds fine, but when I expand the war file I see lots of jar files in the WEB-INF/libs directoy. This is an empty project, there is just an index.jsp file... there should be no jar files included!

How to prevent this from happening?

I'm using Maven 3.0.5 and Eclipse Kepler.

My POM file (auto generated) is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>webclient</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>webclient</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>webclient</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

How to prevent these jars from getting into the created war?

**UPDATE:** Here is the list of files that get included in the war:

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            86,186 aether-api-1.11.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           124,167 aether-impl-1.11.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            15,495 aether-spi-1.11.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           119,828 aether-util-1.11.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           716,139 ant-1.5.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM         1,323,005 ant-1.7.1.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           224,277 ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            12,143 ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            55,639 maven-aether-provider-3.0.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            52,160 maven-artifact-3.0.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           556,983 maven-core-3.0.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           163,439 maven-model-3.0.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           149,093 maven-model-builder-3.0.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            49,200 maven-plugin-api-3.0.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            30,088 maven-repository-metadata-3.0.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            46,677 maven-settings-3.0.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            41,028 maven-settings-builder-3.0.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            13,494 plexus-cipher-1.4.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            47,058 plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM             4,211 plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            61,072 plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM            28,555 plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           223,425 plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           483,594 sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           229,852 sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar

07/05/2013  12:04 PM           195,665 sisu-inject-plexus-2.1.1.jar

Comment: What files are you finding in there?

Comment: Hi Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen and tieTYT, I included the complete list in the post. Thank you!

Comment: Show the `fully-qualified-path` to the files please?

Comment: The fully qualified path is as follows: 

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\target\webclient\WEB-INF\lib

Also, these files are in the WEB-INF\lib directory inside the war file that gets created here:

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\target\webclient.war

Comment: what commands did you execute? I also generated a sample webapp, but couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Did you run maven clean first?

Comment: set the project artifact type to "pom" and then use Maven War plugin and possibly Build-helper or assembly plugin to attach your artifact to the build output.